# Trying to add a new background in iPhone 5 4" storyboard

Tags: objective-c, screen, ios6, iphone-5

I am trying to add a correct sized background image to support iPhone5 4" screen but i am still getting the same letterbox in the bottom. The image is correct sized image. 
The code i use:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == kIphone5) {
        //====THIS IS AN iPhone5 4" screen====//
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_frosty-568h@2x.png"];
        [backgroundImage setImage:image];


    }
```

I do have the lanch image in place..

**UPDATE**

I ended up adding the iPhone5 background image to the iPhone5 Storyboard and use  that for all iPhone modes. Do not know if that is a correct way of doing this but it seems to work.

Can someone please advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just talking about making your app run using the full screen on an iPhone 5 (getting rid of the letterbox)? If so, you don't use the new image size as a background image somewhere in code; you have to add it to your project file as a launch image. See the [Launch Images](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) section of the Apple docs for more info.

Comment: I do have the launch image in place.